# how do i understand this type of C style cast

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ game hacking, not for hacking games, but I am trying to become familiar with memory and editing because I want to get into cyber security field as a job. As a full time job.

I am doing the learncpp tutorials and I have done type casts and understand that this is a C-style type cast problem is I don't understand what it is doing very well.

Here are some snippets.

```
uintptr_t offsetsfunction(uintptr_t localplayer, std::vector<int> offsets) {
    for (int x{ 0 }; x < offsets.size(); ++x) {
        localplayer = *(uintptr_t*)localplayer;
        localplayer += offsets[x];
    }
    return localplayer;
}

// engine is just getmodule
uintptr_t engine = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"ac_client.exe");
// below 
*(int*)offsetfunction(engine + 0x0090FD90, ammooffsets) = infinteAM; // infiteAM contains 1000 

// other ones i struggle with.
playerent * localPlayer = (playerent*)*(DWORD*)(0x509B74);
```

The `*(int*)` is a dereference typecast `int` pointer `offsetfunction`
which dereferences the `offsetfunction` as a type of `int` pointer?

The bottom `playerent` is creating a pointer that equals
`(player*)` <-- typecast player type IDK what type but okay.
then `*(DWORD*)` dereferences dword pointer (address) and store all of that in `localplayer` pointer?

I'm quite confused by it, could somebody please explain it for me?

Comment: The return value of `offsetfunction` is being cast to an int pointer, that pointer is being dereferenced and `infinteAM` is being assigned to the dereferenced location. I think that is what you are saying as well, so I don't see where your confusion is. Maybe you just wanted confirmation?

Comment: Generally speaking, any time you feel the need to use, or see, a C-style cast in C++ code, you should take that as a sign that there's something bad or wrong going on.

Comment: @john Yes so i was correct? The bottom one is a little more confusing

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes i could use static_cast from C++ but im trying to learn C style also as alot of programs are written in C so i want a good understanding of both

Comment: In the second example, `0x509874` is being interpreted (cast) as a DWORD pointer. Then that DWORD pointer is being dereferenced and the resulting DWORD value is being interpreted as another pointer (a playerent pointer).

Comment: The statement `*(int*)offsetfunction(engine + 0x0090FD90, ammooffsets) = infinteAM;` is equivalent to `uintptr_t result = offsetfunction(engine + 0x0090FD90, ammooffsets); int *result_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(result); *result_ptr = infinteAM;`

Comment: @peterevans This code keeps breaking type-safety. It is indicative of a C-mindset and especially if you are looking to do security stuff, this is a terrible habit to get into. There are zero reasons to do c-style casts. Zero. In fact, I'd recommend enabling compiler warnings for them. If you really really really need to reinterpret a value, use `reinterpret_cast` but use it sparingly.

Comment: @peterevans Seem you might be reading the last example backwards, try reading it right to left.

Comment: My advice is that if you want to learn C++, learn C++ properly. Don't use C++ as "C with classes" or similar, that won't make you a good C++ programmer (or a good C programmer for that matter). Also, "hacking" exercises like that won't make you a good programmer either.

Comment: @john so the first ```*(int *)offsetfunction(engine + 0x0090FD90, ammooffsets) = infinteAMl ``` is not being cast to any location so its casting it onto its self?

Comment: @john Seem you might be reading the last example backwards, try reading it right to left. Which one the offsetfunction or both

Comment: @peterevans Not sure what you mean by cast to a location. You cannot cast to a location. When you cast one pointer type to another pointer type all you are doing is **reinterpreting** that pointer as a new type.

Comment: @john makes sense what about the last one

Comment: @peterevans I meant the last one, the DWORD one.

Comment: @bitmask i understand that i just see it alot espically when i reverse stuff with IDA and look at the code, Understand that it is bad but im trying to learn everything

Comment: @john so it should all be read from left to right when looking at C style casts like this

Comment: @peterevans I've already given my interpretation of the second example.

Comment: @peterevans No, I said right to left. (X*)(Y*)(Z*)ptr. The Z* cast is applied first

Comment: Step 1: invest 3-5 years in thoroughly learning C++, the most complicated and hardest to learn general purpose programming language in use today, and all of its core fundamentals, like pointers. Step 2: learn "game hacking", whatever that is. Which step are you on?

Comment: @peterevans And I wasn't proposing a general rule, I just said I thought you were interpreting that particular expression the wrong way round. I might have been wrong.

Comment: @john okay now it makes sense so read them both right to left okay that makes more sense to me thank you

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ive been learning about pointers for like 2 months and C++ for about 1 month so far i had some prior experince in C just basic but never could understand pointers very well im learning both 50/50

Comment: @john if you wanna put that as an answer i can make this thread complete thank you just to clarify i should read C style casts backwards and not left to right

Comment: Are you able to run this code in a debugger? Or output the data? The `uintptr_t` casting looks like a bit of  red-herring. It's common and it appears on that platform that the offsets being added to the `localplayer' are memory offsets. It's not guaranteed but it's more than likely that adding an offset the `localplayer` `uintptr_t` amounts to adding the same offset to a char* pointer. And if that doesn't make sense I strongly recommend you look at some simpler code because there's some exotic shenanigans going on here.

Comment: the offsets are memory offsets yes also no unfortunatly i cannot because it is an internal Cheat that i can't attach a debugger too

Comment: What is the platform? As I said, I suspect that these casts all amount to pure reinterpretation with no translation of bit pattern. In terms of your original question I think you do understand it.

Comment: Its for assault cube windows. And so ```ent* localPlayer = *(ent**)(moduleBase + 0x10F4F4);``` is casting module + address to ent** derference to get result and store it inside of localplayer ?

Comment: So it's a 32-bit engine? The mention of `DWORD` made me wonder.

Comment: Yes its 32bits @Persixty

Comment: @peterevans Unfortunately someone has picked an almost random vaguely similar but somewhat unrelated question and closed this as a duplicate. But in fact I think you understand it. It's some hacky code that gayly sloshes around between pointers, `uintptr_t` and `DWORD` which on a 32-bit platform is practically an alias for `uintptr_t` anyway. It will raise lots of portability flags but it's in a game engine originally built for specific hardware platform so such concerns are moot.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. So just for one final time. I should read it from right to left and store the result in the end

Comment: @peterevans We've probably all seen code like that. The development team probably never had a clear guide when to use the rag-bag of pointer and shift like types we see there and in fact the castingfuck (like clusterfuck but for datatypes) we see is confusing but benign.

Comment: @Persixty Yeah true its good for me to learn though am i correct with what i was saying though read from right to left instead of left to right in type cast conversions like that